# Odoo 10 starting wrong with systemd service using config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, systemd, odoo-10

I have been running my odoo 10 installation with command /opt/odoo/odoo10.0/odoo-bin and it has worked fine.

Now I want to create a service to enable/start/stop it when i want. I'v been trying to accomplish it with systemd, but the odoo starts differently than with the script above.

When I start it as a service it thinks that I'm using it for the first time and asks to create a database etc. Like It's not using the config file. Have I made something wrong?

This is my service file /etc/systemd/system/odoo.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM
Requires=postgresql.service
After=network.target postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
SyslogIdentifier=odoo-server
User=odoo
Group=odoo
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf
WorkingDirectory=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that you have not provided the path to your addons directory in /etc/systemd/system/odoo.service:

as per your current installation, change the  line

> ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf

to

> ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf
>   --addons-path=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons/

then reload systemctl:

> systemctl daemon-reload

finally restart odoo service:

> systemctl restart odoo.service

Hope this helps.